# Screen completely screwed up when in dual screen in Unity

Tags: unity, ati, multiple-monitors

Ok, I read Unity has problems when in dual screen mode, but this seems something different from the bug I read filed.

As soon as I attach the secondary screen I get both screens completely screwed up like the image attached. Here something about the desktop can be seen, some other times only lines could be seen.

[image]

I'm using ATI with opensource drivers and kernel 2.6.39 (2.6.38 wasn't working and 2.6.35 was doing the same).
Do not suggest please to install proprietary ATI drivers cause on 11.04 those won't install. Still investigating why, in case I'll ask another separate question :-)

Anyone else experiencing the same? Have you ever encountered a similar bugreport? Should I report this? Thanks!

Comment: Never found information about this. Reported here, in case anyone else is interested: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/786728.

Comment: Close to vote. This was a bug and should be fixed in 11.04 with updates and in 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reset unity after reconfiguring the display setup?

```
$ unity --reset &
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing Alt+F2 and typing "unity --replace" once you have the second screen connected? This helps with similar bugs. Also, try to connect it before you log in (or, alternatively, connect the second screen and reboot).

Comment: Nothing has changed with the first advice. Connecting before logging results in the secondary screen mirroring correctly the primary (I want dual screen, not mirroring). After logging in, if I try to change the setup, I get the same behavior of the question.